# comparison in if construct using a variable is not working in awk

Tags: unix, awk

I have sorted a file on the basis of a integer column and the sorting is working as expected

```
sort -t '~' -k 118 GCW_Distributor_AMS.nonpublishBkp2 > GCW_Distributor_AMS.nonpublishBkp4
```

I am feeding the sorted file into an awk command

```
awk -F'~' 'BEGIN{ OFS="\034"; incr=1; startIID=100252868641; PrevIID=0 }
{ 
    if(PrevIID!=$118)
    {
        prevIID = $118; 
        $118 = startIID + incr; 
        incr+=1;
    } 
    else if(PrevIID==$118)
    { 
        $118= startIID + incr;
    } 
print
}' GCW_Distributor_AMS.nonpublishBkp4 > GCW_Distributor_AMS.nonpublish
```

The expectation out of this awk code is that if there are duplicates values the dont increment the `incr` variable.

Example
Sorted file on the basis of IID

```
Depname   IID
cs        100
ec        200  
mec       200
ap        300
```

in the above example i want to increment the IID with 1 ( the starting IID is 1000 instead of 100) so that the above example becomes like below

```
Depname   IID
cs        1001
ec        1002  
mec       1002
ap        1003
```

but this is not happening , instead the file is coming like below

```
Depname   IID
cs        1001
ec        1002  
mec       1003
ap        1004
```

As per the expectation 1002 should come two times.

The PrevIID comparison is not working in the `if` construct.

I verified that the input file is sorted properly.

Any Idea?

Comment: Could you please post samples(in your question) of your input file to make it more clear, thank you.

Comment: Please fix your [mcve] so that the code you provide works with the example you provide rather than with some other input we can't see that has at least 118 fields instead of 2 and is `~`-separated instead of space-separated, and get rid of the stuff about sorting some other input to create the input for the script you're asking for help with as that's irrelevant and just cluttering up your question.

Comment: Also - your code doesn't attempt to address your input having a header line (`Depname   IID`) so if your actual input doesn't have a header line then don't show a header line in  the example in your question as that just complicates any potential solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your awk script looks a bit too complicated to me. See below for a simpler version. The problem probably comes from 1) a case mismatch (`prevIID` instead of `PrevIID`) and 2) the logic: if the field you monitor changes, say from 100 to 200, you increment. So the next line will be impacted, even if it has the same field. On your simplified example you would have:

```
         incr before  incr after  printed
cs  100  1            2           cs  1001
ec  200  2            3           ec  1002
mec 200  3            3           mec 1003
ap  300  3            4           ap  1003
```

This second bug just shifts the expected behavior by one line, different from what you wrote (probably because of the first case mismatch bug):

```
cs        1001
ec        1002
mec       1003
ap        1004
```

Just in case it helps here is a simpler script (with the default field separators) that would work with your simplified example (without the header line).

```
awk -v startIID=1000 'BEGIN{c=startIID;p=""} $2!=p{c+=1;p=$2} {$2=c;print}'
```

Demo:

```
$ cat foo.txt
cs        100
ec        200  
mec       200
ap        300
$ awk -v startIID=1000 'BEGIN{c=startIID; p=""} $2!=p{c+=1;p=$2} {$2=c;print}' foo.txt
cs 1001
ec 1002
mec 1002
ap 1003
```

Comment: Yes. The issue was due to case mismatch. I have corrected it and the script worked.

Comment: I am a bit surprised .Why is the shell not showing any syntax Error?

Comment: What shell? Your error was in the `awk` script, not in a shell script. And `awk` accepts uninitialized variables. It just considers that they have an empty value. Just like most shells, by the way, unless you ask them to flag undeclared variables. This is one of the many things to learn with a new language.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    OFS = "\t"
    cnt = 1000
}
NR > 1 {
    cnt += ($2 != prev)
    prev = $2
    $2 = cnt
}
{ print }
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
Depname   IID
cs      1001
ec      1002
mec     1002
ap      1003
```